# Angular (4): ng-href for angular material 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is there something like `ng-href` but for angular 4 and angular material 2, so that I can navigate to another site by using `md-button`?

Thanks!

Comment: @Vega yes correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add mat-button directive to a link, according to [Angular Material 2 documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api#directives).

Example:

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" mat-button color="primary">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://outerLink" class="link" md-button color="primary">Something</a>
```

or you can use routerLink in your project Server pages like

```
<a [routerLink]="['localPath']">Something</a>
```